# Are override methods considered virtual methods?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Taken from Eric Gunnerson's blog "[virtual functions are not inlined](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx)", but what qualifies as a virtual method? MSDN defines it as:

> "When an instance method declaration includes a virtual modifier, that method is said to be a virtual method. When no virtual modifier is present, the method is said to be a non-virtual method." - [MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Strictly speaking, a derived class with the override method `public override void SomeMethod(){}`" does not contain the word `virtual`, so could it be inlined?

**Edit**: Specifically, the question is whether the overrided method is a candidate for inlining, since the two links I've provided are too vague on overrided methods.

Comment: You can't override a not-virtual method. Whether a method is virtual ("may be overriden in subclasses") or not is determined at the top of its inheritance chain. (Give or take sealing and re-opening but I don't really know all the edge cases of those modifiers.)

Comment: @millimoose Can you cite a source? That's in direct opposition of what the MSDN article states.

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @Mr.Smith What I'm saying is that a method declared as `override` must already have been declared as `virtual` up the inheritance chain. Therefore, all `override` methods are already `virtual`. To put it differently, if you have the method `virtual void Foo()` on the class `Animal`, and `override void Foo()` in the class `Dog : Animal`, you can think of them as different implementations of *the same* method. (As far as the class structure is concerned.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From §1.6.6.4 Virtual, override, and abstract methods of the C# 4.0 specification (you were quoting an older version):

> A virtual method can be *overridden* in a derived class. When an instance method declaration includes an `override` modifier, the method overrides an inherited virtual method with the same signature. Whereas a virtual method declaration *introduces* a new method, an override method declaration *specializes* an existing inherited virtual method by providing a new implementation of that method.

So, when you write an `override` method, you're not actually creating a new method, you're just overriding a method. And that one has to be `virtual`, so the method you're actually calling is virtual.

That being said, there are cases where a virtual method can be inlined: if the compile-time type of the object in question is `sealed`, then there is no doubt what code to execute. (I believe .Net actually does *not* use this optimization.)

But in other cases, virtual methods cannot be inlined.

Comment: What if the sealed type in question is a value type? (Not a rhetorical question; I honestly do not know if the jitter inlines overridden virtual methods of value types. I see no reason why it could not.)

Comment: @EricLippert No idea, I'm basing the claim that .Net doesn't perform this optimization on a short note in [an article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/01/20/aggressive-inlining-in-the-clr-4-5-jit.aspx), I didn't actually look at the generated assembly code myself.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that override virtual methods are definitely virtual. In many ways, they are all the same method as the one they override. They use something called a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). They point of the blog that you reference is that the compiler will optimize what it can, but since a virtual/overridden method has a look-up involved, it cannot be simplified.